# Android database insert crash

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

Whenever I press the button to insert data to the table my app crashes.

### The Database handler

```
public class MyDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME="TranslateGame.db";
    private static final String Table_Name="TranslateGame";
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_ENGLISH="EnglishList";
    private static final String KEY_HEBREW="HebrewList";

    public MyDBHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CreateGameSql="Create Table"+Table_Name+"("+
                KEY_ID+"INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
                KEY_ENGLISH+"TEXT, "
                +KEY_HEBREW+"TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(CreateGameSql);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Table_Name);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void AddWord(TranslateTable translate) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_ENGLISH,translate.GetEnglish());
        values.put(KEY_HEBREW,translate.GetHebrew());
        db.insert(Table_Name, null, values);
        db.close();
    }

    public String[] GetTranslation(String Word)
    {
        String[] Arr={KEY_ID,KEY_ENGLISH,KEY_HEBREW};
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor=db.query(DATABASE_NAME,Arr,null,null,null,null,null);
        if (cursor!=null)
        {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return Arr;
    }

    public List<TranslateTableGetDataBaseInfo()
    {
        List<TranslateTabledbInfo=new ArrayList<>();
        String SelectQuery="SELECT * FROM"+Table_Name;
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery(SelectQuery,null);
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                TranslateTable NewTable=new TranslateTable();
                NewTable.SetID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                NewTable.SetEnglish(cursor.getString(1));
                NewTable.SetHebrew(cursor.getString(2));
                dbInfo.add(NewTable);
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return dbInfo;
    }
}
```

### Insert Data Activity

```
public class MainPage extends AppCompatActivity {
    MyDBHandler Newdb;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_page);
        Newdb=new MyDBHandler(this);
    }

    public void AddWord(View view) {
        EditText OriginalWord=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Original);
        EditText TranslationWord=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Translation);
        if(OriginalWord.getText().toString().isEmpty()||TranslationWord.getText().toString().isEmpty())
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please fill the empty texts", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
            TranslateTable NewTable=new TranslateTable(OriginalWord.getText().toString(),
                    TranslationWord.getText().toString());
            Newdb.AddWord(NewTable);
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: You need to provide the stacktrace for the crash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing I see is that you don´t have a white space here:

```
"Create Table"+Table_Name
```

It must be:

```
String CreateGameSql="Create Table "+Table_Name+"("+
                KEY_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
                KEY_ENGLISH+"TEXT, "
                +KEY_HEBREW+"TEXT)";
```

Your create string is correct except after `Create table` and after `KEY_ID`. In SQLite, every value must be separated.

Answer (score 3):

Just add spaces.

```
 String CreateGameSql="Create Table "+Table_Name+" ( "+
                KEY_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , "+
                KEY_ENGLISH+" TEXT , "
                +KEY_HEBREW+" TEXT )";
```

Comment: His string is correct except the one space after `Create table`...everywhere else, there is a space.

Comment: but use space for better clarity and easily find out solution